# When does IE delete files from Temporary folder?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, internet-explorer-8, temporary-directory

Our application is a ASP.NET + Flex running on IIS 6.0 server. On the client machines we run IE8 for display. IE creates temp files that seems to be taking up disk space. The Temporary Internet Folder size continues to grow seems to exceed the limit of 8MB - automatic recycle. When and under what conditions does IE delete files from the temporary folders?

Comment: Are the client machines mobile devices?

Comment: See my comment below the first answer. IE is very tricky - does not do what it says it will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to review the following: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301057

Also, you should know that the temp internet folder isn't used by just the browser.  It's actually built into the OS.  As such, there are numerous other programs that might be leveraging that code and causing temp files to be stored.  This generally causes storage to go beyond whatever you have it set to.

Regarding the 8MB limit.. That's pretty small... For IE8 up the recommended minimum size is 50MB.

Comment: Finally found out that IE's behavior is inconsitent. If the size of C:\Documents and Settings\[User name]\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Conent.IE5 folder exceeds the set limit, then IE WILL NOT delete the files automatically and any new temp file will continue to eat away at the disk space. Depending on the application it can grow really fast. Try running ten browsers viewing a YouTube video and you will see the disk space eat-away real fast. Only option is to navigate to folder and run a 'del *. /s' in a CMD window.